# Can dissolved salts (or any soluble chemicals, for that matter) 'bump' each other out of solubility?

Tags: solubility

Will a more soluble substance dissociate, causing a less soluble substance to precipitate out?

in equation:

AB(s)+ C(aq)+ D(aq)--> A(aq)+ B(aq)+ CD(s)

Does that equation go through, under the assumptions that AB, as a whole, is more soluble than CD, and saturation point is achieved with both substances?

Thanks in advance! This question has been bothering me for a while...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this effect is termed [*salting out*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salting_out) for non-ionic compounds and [*the common ion effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-ion_effect) for ionic ones.

Note that in specific cases, the *converse* may hold true. For example, "the solubility of silver chloride in water is reduced if a solution of sodium chloride is added to a suspension of silver chloride in water (op cit)." However, *adding more chloride re-dissolves the precipitate* [due to the formation of complex ions](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/3_d-Block_Elements/Group_11%3A_Transition_Metals/Chemistry_of_Silver/Silver_Chloride):

$\ce{AgCl(s) + Cl- (aq) -> AgCl2- (aq)}$

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking about the common ion effect. More like $$\ce{KNO3_{(s)} + Ag^+_{(aq)} + Cl^{-}_{(aq)} -> K^+{(aq)} + NO3^{-}_{(aq)} + AgCl_{(s)}}$$ which I think would have the opposite effect. I'd expect $\ce{AgCl}$ to be more soluble in a $\ce{KNO3}$ solution.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. So if I was to put sugar into saturation point salt water, the salt would precipitate out?